# Syntax understanding in C: Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I have medium knowledge working with pointers. Some of the syntax styles baffles me.

Like:

1. `*(uint8 *) (a) = (b)`
2. typecasting the reference when parsing it in a function. The  function is prototyped as `func(unsigned char * a);` but it is used as `func((unsigned short *) &b);` .... As far I understand they were casting a expected char type pointer into a short.

Can anyone help me understand what these statements exactly mean in C?

Comment: Please tyke the [tour] and provide a [mcve]. You might also want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what definitions mean in C take a look at the right-left rule, it's very simple and explains a lot http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html. What it basically means is that you start out with the name and move right building up the definition then move left only when you can't move right. This might sound weird but let's take an example with number 1.

1. *(uint8 *) (a) = (b)

   So step 1 what is a? Start with the name of the variable which in this case is a. Then look to see what is defined to the right of that, here it is nothing, so move to the part immediately to the right, which is (uint8 *). Which means that a is a pointer to a uint8. Ok now move right from the uint8* and you get back to a so that means you can't move right anymore, so go right then which gets you *, which is the dereferencing a. So for this line the uint8 stored at the address a is set to the value of b.
2. Ok for the second part I think the `func((unsigned short *) &b)` is where they begin defining the function body? If that is case then that means for the function body the passed in parameter is used as a pointer to an unsigned short, but if the function is called like this I think the compiler wouldn't be happy because of the type mismatch since the function is expecting an `unsigned char *` not an `unsigned short *`.

Comment: Thanks, I remember reading the right hand side rule from my school and that's how I read things if I donot understand, but the use of brackets always throws me off.. for instance in 1. I start from a go right see a bracket close and then I start moving left there is a bracket again arount uint8, how do you interpret that??

Comment: Well think of brackets like their own little worlds. You do everything inside the bracket first and then move one. For example if you   have int[] * a (int *). You would start with a then move right to the (int *). When you see () after the name it means that it is function taking in a parameter. So here we have a as a function taking in a pointer to an int as a parameter. After this you can't go right anymore so you go left to the *. So we get a is a function that takes in a pointer to an int as a parameter returning a pointer to... You can't go left so you go right again to the [] so we have

Comment: a as a function taking in a pointer to an int as a parameter returning a pointer to an array of.... Once more you can't go right since you already went right so you go left leading you to the "int" which leaves us with our final answer  "a is a function taking in a pointer to an int as a parameter returning a pointer to an array of ints". I am probabally not to great at explaining this so read the link in the post which is pretty clear about it. Also check out this website which translates C declarations to English http://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 0):

The first one simply casts `(a)` into a pointer to an unsigned 8-bit integer, then writes the result of evaluating `(b)` to the resulting address (as an 8-bit number).

The second one isn't valid, it shouldn't compile. Perhaps you mis-remember, it's a bit sketchy-looking.

Comment: In second example, ´b´ could be ´unsigned short b;´, isn't? I think it compiles depending on C implementation... ¿?

Comment: @jabujavi: Problem isn't the `&b` cast to `unsigned short*` (well, it is, but it wouldn't be a compile-time error). The problem is calling a function that takes an `unsigned char*` parameter, with an `unsigned short*` argument.

Comment: @unwind .... Ya I thought the compiler should throw an error too but I I donot misremember it

Comment: @unwind .... Ya I thought the compiler should throw an error too but I I donot misremember it     function definition: int func(unsigned char *ptr) and it is used as func((unsigned short *)&a), where a is defined as a "short". I assure you it compiles and works as this piece of code runs on a machine out in the field from last 15 years... As far as the use goes , when parsed a short type pointer does the definition typecast it to a char type pointer??

Comment: since pointers to character type are allowed to access objects of any type, the second example is not necessarily undefined.

Comment: True , so a pointer of type char can hold a short...Its going to be all fine as long as we are dealing with references and not the actual value it is pointing to. But once we try to dereference that particular address, the program would give some kind of segmentation fault as on dereferencing a "ptr" it would be expecting a value which would fit in 1 byte of data but we have a value which would be needing 2 bytes of data................Is my logic sound about this????